# Moving files in shell script and copying files to the same folder at the same time

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script to move all files from one directory to other. Say I want to move all files from directory dirA to directory dirB. When the move is in progress, some user is copying some files to dirA. How do I ensure that, whatever file the shell script is trying to move, has finished copying? What would happen if we try to move a file which is still being copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of filenames is generated as soon as the move command is issued. Any changes after that will not be taken into account. So if new files are created during the move process, they won't get impacted.

You may have to run your script in a loop.

If one of the files that is part of the move command is still being modified (after being opened in its old place), the changes would
propagate to the new place when the change operation is complete and the file is closed.